# Recommended Open Source C# algorithms & data structures libraries

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

What algorithms libraries can you recommend? The basic criteria are:

- Capabilities
- Object Oriented Design
- Performance

Algorithms libraries I have used and can recommend:

- [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) - for graph algorithms
- [C5](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) - for data structures that have not been included in .NET framework
- [NetTopologySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/) - for spatial processing and algorithms

I haven't found any good text/string algorithm library and 2D Geometry library.

Comment: QuickGraph! I wished I encountered on it earlier.

Comment: Interesting question ... what is your goal? To teach an algo class in C#?

Comment: Open source is a broad term. Do you mean free-as-in-speech? GPL? LGPL? Public domain? Microsoft's shared source license? Or any of the above?

Comment: Was about to recommend C5, until I saw it in your list. Very nice library :)

Answer (score 1):

[Aumplib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Aumplib.aspx) namespace for Audio Conversion

Answer (score 1):

[Wintellect's Power Collections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @hims056 Why just this answer? almost all the answers are just a URL.  Side-effect of the question.

Answer (score 1):

[NCalc - C# embedable extensible mathematical expression library](http://ncalc.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 1):

[SharpMap - Geospacial application framework for the CLR](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out my open source project, called NList. It is found at http://nlist.codeplex.com.

NList has a library of algorithms similar to those provided by C++'s STL, but geared for.NET development. It also has a powerful text generator similar to handlebars.js. NList has one of the best custom comparison builders out there. There's a class for treating an object like a dictionary of its properties. There's a default dictionary class. There's also a conversion method that "just works". Plus there are a few other collection wrappers.

Comment: You could say wht it is about as well..